Linux Lite не удалось выполнить дочерний процесс
Всем приветик. Недавно поставила себе Linux Lite, поскольку нашла очень старенький ноут, и захотелось его как-то оживить. До поры до времени работало нормально. Поставила Google Chrome, установила его как браузер по умолчанию, после чего он просто перестал открывать какие либо внешние ссылки, и выдает ошибку. несколько дней искала в чем может быть ошибка, но так и не нашла

Пробовала переустанавливать браузер, ноль эффектов. Помогите пожалуйста...

Посмотрите на права (это rwx...) в выводе ls -l /usr/bin/xfce4-mime-helper

Отыщите в настройках системы что-то похожее на "программы по умолчанию" и настройте там программу, которая будет браузером по умолчанию.

Именно так я и сделала. Собственно после этого ошибка и появилась
